# userfunc check if NOT true [userFunc != user_myfunc]

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I try to check if a userFunc is NOT true.

It works with ELSE:

```
[userFunc = user_myfunc]
    #function returns true
[ELSE]
    #function returns false
[end]
```

But what I realy want is: (that does not work!)

```
[userFunc != user_myfunc]
    #function returns false
[end]
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

The reason I want to do it is: I want to check if myfunc is false and myfunc2 is true. Something like this:

```
[userFunc != user_myfunc] && [userFunc = user_myfunc2]
    #user_myfunc returns false & user_myfunc2 returns true
[end]
```

Comment: To negate a conditions, you have to use [CONDITION][ELSE]Stuff[END]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a "not" parameter to my function.

```
[userFunc != user_myfunc]
```

is getting:

```
[userFunc = user_myfunc(not)]
```

and in the function itself I do:

```
if($not=="not") { // $not is the parameter of the function
        return !$returnvalue; // so is the parameter set to "not" I return the oposide.
    } else {
        return $returnvalue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, only an equal comparison is possible:

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#id2
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-userfunc

The best thing would be to write a combine userFunc which does both evaluations.

The code that proves that it's impossible to negate the userFunc is here:
https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Configuration/TypoScript/ConditionMatching/AbstractConditionMatcher.php#L421

Comment: I'm not sure if thats 100% correct. Search on the same page for `!=` and you will find some "not equal" examples. I tried different things like: `[userFunc = != user_myfunc]` and `[userFunc = user_myfunc, != true]`. Maybe it is just not possible with a userFunc..

Comment: I also think that only `=` is possible because it is your function that should return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, thus controlling whether the conditional statements are used or not.

Comment: @cascaval I now think, that the `=` in userFunc is not an operator, it's just a char. The function itself is taken as condition. So you are right the returnvalue of the function is taken as condition without comparing the returnvalue to something else.